# Captcha validation did not match please try again

Tags: php, captcha

I have a validation problem with my Captcha. Here is some of the code from the newaccount file.

When I try to register it says :

> The "CAPTCHA you entered did not match please try again.

I have gotten it to work sometimes and that was on chrome but it's very unstable.

```
<?php session_start();
include ('connect.php');
require_once ('locale/'.$locale.'/'.$locale.'.php');
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $username = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['usernames']));
  $password = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['passwords']));
  $email = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
  $security = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['security']));
} else {
  $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['usernames']);
  $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['passwords']);
  $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
  $security = htmlspecialchars($_POST['security']);
}
 if(strlen($security) < 4) {
  echo "<span class='infos alert'>$phrase[237] </span>";
  die();
 }
 if((@$_POST['security']) <> @$_SESSION['captcha']) {
  echo "<span class='infos alert'>$phrase[237] </span>";
  session_unset();
  session_destroy();
  die();
  } 
if(strlen($username) < 4) {
  echo "<span class='infos alert'>$phrase[111] </span>";
  die();
}
if(strlen($username) > 20) {
  echo "<span class='infos alert'>$phrase[109] </span>";
  die();
}
if(strlen($password) < 4) {
  echo "<span class='infos alert'>$phrase[112] </span>";
  die();
}
if(strlen($password) > 20) {
  echo "<span class='infos alert'>$phrase[110] </span>";
  die();
}
if(preg_match("/ /",$username)) {
  echo "<span class='infos alert'>$phrase[108]</span>";
  die();
}
if(preg_match("/ /",$password)) {
  echo "<span class='infos alert'>$phrase[108]</span>";
  die();
}
if(preg_match('/\./',$username)) {
  echo "<span class='infos alert'>$phrase[232]</span>";
  die();
}
if(strlen($email) < 5) {
  echo "<span class='infos alert'>$phrase[128]</span>";
  die();
}
if(strlen($email) > 60) {
  echo "<span class='infos alert'>$phrase[127]</span>";
  die();
}
if(!preg_match("/([A-Z0-9_-]+\@[A-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-z.]{2,7}+)+$/i",$email)) {
  echo "<span class='infos alert'>$phrase[129]</span>";
  die();
}
```

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fact you applied `htmlspecialchars` before your different tests. Doing that may cause various problems: 1) tests based on `strlen` becomes wrong *(if the username is `&` it becomes `&amp;` that is longer than 4 characters)*. 2) the comparison between in `$_POST['security']` and `$_SESSION['captcha']` becomes wrong too when `$_POST['security']` contains a special html character. `htmlspecialchars` is only useful when you have to display a variable content inside html.

Comment: As an aside, many aspect of this code seems very old, you have rewrite it entirely using current practises.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes it is old. Now I know where to start.